# How to split multiple typed index out to prepare for ES upgrade (where multiple types are deprecated)

Tags: elasticsearch, types, upgrade

We are currently running a cluster with ES 2.3.2 that has one large index with the following properties:

- 762 GB (366 million docs)
- 25 data nodes; 3 master nodes; 3 client nodes
- 23 shards / 1 replica

This one index has 20+ types, each with a few common and many unique fields.  I am redesigning the cluster with the following goals:

1) Remove multiple types in an index so that we can upgrade ES.  Though multi-types are supported in v5, we want to do the work to prep for v6 now.
2) Break up the large index into more manageable smaller indexes

I have set up a new identical cluster.  I modified the indexing so that I have one index per type.  I allocated a shard count based on the relative size of the data with a minimum of 2, and a max of 5 shards.  After indexing all of our data into this new cluster, I am finding that the same query against the new cluster is slower than against the old cluster.

I figured this was due to the explosion of shards (i.e. was 23 primary, and now it is 78).  I closed all but one index (that has a shard count of 2), then ran a test where I targeted a single type against my old monolithic index, and the new single-typed index (using a homebrew tool to run requests in parallel and parse out the "took").  I find that if I do a "size: 0", my new cluster is faster.  When I return 7 or 8 they seem to be in parity.  It then goes downhill where our default query of 30 records returned is about twice as slow.  I am guessing this is because there are fewer threads to do the actual retrieval in the smaller index with two shards vs the large one with 23.

What is the recommendation for moving away from multi-typed indexes when the following is true:
- There are many types
- The types have very different mappings
- There is a huge variance in size per type running from 4 mb to 154 gb

I am currently contemplating putting them all in one type with one massive mapping (I don't think there are any fields with the same name but different mappings), but that seems really ugly.

Any suggestions welcome,

Thanks,
~john

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data but you can try to lessen the indexes in the following way.

Those types that have similar mappings group in one index. In this index create property "type" and support this property by yourself in queries.

If every type has completely different structure I would put the smaller ones in one index. After all they were this way before.

Answer (score 0):

Sharding is the way how elasticsearch scales, so it makes sense that you observe performance degradation for network/IO bound operation when it's executed against 2 shard vs. 23, as it essentially means it was run on 2 nodes in parallel as opposed to 23.

If you want to split the index, you need to go over all of the types and identify the minimum number of shards for each type for your target performance. It'll depend on multiple factors such as the number of documents, document size, request/indexing patterns. As you mentioned that types vary significantly in size, most likely the result will be less balanced than your initial set up (2-5 shards), i.e. some of the indexes will need a higher number of shards, while some will do fine with less, e.g. there is no need to split 4mb index (as in your example) into multiple shards, unless you expect it to grow significantly and have high update rate and you want to scale indexing, otherwise 1 shard is fine.